# dpkg issue while trying to install insight from PPA - trying to overwrite... which is also in

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, dpkg, ppa

When trying to install insight from some PPA repositories, but I get errors.

```
sudo apt-get install insight
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  insight
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,298 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,787 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  insight
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
(Reading database ... 232356 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../insight_6.8.1-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking insight (6.8.1-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/insight_6.8.1-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libinproctrace.so', which is also in package gdbserver 7.8-1ubuntu4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/insight_6.8.1-0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The package is trying to overwrite files which are maintained by a different package.  The dpkg error indicates that the insight package is trying to overwrite a file managed by gdbserver.

You can't have two packages managing the same file in the packaging system's mind, so it errors.

I would suggest that you investigate the PPA and reach out to the PPA maintainers to indicate this conflict and then see what they say.  Alternatively, don't install the package you're trying to install.

Also consider the package can't be verified so I would question the integrity of the package (that is to say the package doesn't have a validateable signature on it so I would not suggest use of it)

Answer (score 0):

The version of insight you have in your APT cache seems to be corrupted.

So to fix this, remove it like this:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/insight_6.8.1 0ubuntu0~sevenmachines1_amd64.deb
```

and run then this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f;sudo apt-get update
```

This will force apt-get to download another (hopefully not corrupted) version of insight, which should install without problems, and then it will update it. Hope this helps, if it works, maybe please accept it by clicking on the grey tick under the answer's votes :)

I had the same problem yesterday and thanks to **@kos** I fixed it and you possibly can too :D